# Enquire button not aligning to center

Tags: html, css

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="tex-align:center">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enquire</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
   alert("Thank you, your enquiry has been submitted!");
}
</script>
</td>
</tr>
```

My enquire button will not move from the left of the page. I had a previous button that had no function and used a different code to make a popup box happen. It works, but the previous style and colspan codes have no effect on the new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a spelling mistake in your code:
you gave

```
tex-align:center;
```

Its..

```
text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 2):

The word `text` has two `t`s in it.

```
style="text-align:center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
style="text-align:center"
```

and add some CSS to the HTML table:

```
table{
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ny2boknz/)